# WiX 4 remove "Do not close applications" option from FilesInUse

Tags: wix, wix4

I'm using WiX 4.0.1. The "Files In Use" dialog displays an option that says "Do not close applications. A reboot will be required." I would like to force the user to either exit the installation or close the file in use.

I looked at uilt:CloseApplication, but it has an "Ignore" option.

Is there any other way to accomplish this?